Card-fighting, battle-based cartoon/anime where the cards transform
I’ve been trying to find this cartoon for the longest time ever. I’m not sure what exactly the details are but I remember it was kind of like Yugi-Oh in the sense that it was a card fighting battle based show.
However, instead of only monsters appearing, the cards would also be able to transform them into other areas/environments and usually the battles would be against two opponents with the rest of the people viewing it from huge screens inside.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

This sounds somewhat like Card Captor Sakura.
